# In MATLAB , NANs in during training neural network

Tags: matlab, deep-learning, neural-network

I encountered a very strange problem while using Matlab 2016a Using a neural network built into the Perceptron NNtool toolbox, I try to predict a nonlinear variable. However, during training, the values obtained are for testing and training and validation of NANs. I tried to change the learning speed and hide the layers, but nothing worked. Do you have any idea, why is this so? Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please improve this question with a reproducible code sample or link to the example.

Comment: trainTargets = t .* tr.trainMask{1};
valTargets = t .* tr.valMask{1};
testTargets = t .* tr.testMask{1};                                                                                   In this section, the values of NANs are evaluated, trained and retested.